# how to save the action in android?

Tags: java, android

In My app i have button ,i can enable and disable,if go to next activity and if i come back it should show where i left off.

```
up1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adultup1);     
up1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
    public void onClick(View view) {                
        if(upt[0]==0){
            up1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultup1);
            upt[0]=1;
        }else{
            up1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultup1_pressed);
            upt[0]=0;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try user preferences:

```
private static void saveBooleanProperty(String key, boolean value) 
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = YourClass.getInstance().getSharedPreferences();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private static boolean getBooleanProperty(String key, boolean defaultValueIfNotExist)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = YourClass.getInstance().getSharedPreferences();
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValueIfNotExist);
}
```

Comment: how can i access this when i press back button

Comment: First you should saveBooleanProperty() when you need it,then call getBooleanProperty()  by your key for example ADULTUP in OnResume() and set this boolean value to your button.

Comment: here we took one key,becs one butto, i have 32 buttons in single scree so is it possible

Comment: Create Array<Boolean>buttonState and save all their states. SaveBooleanArray() - getBooleanArray();for(int = 0; i < 32;i++) saveBooleanArray(i); // save your button state here

Comment: so before go to next activity i need to save states of button in array and when i press back button i need to call getboolean property

Answer (score 0):

Check for up1.isEnabled().
This should be the easiest way out.